# How to select all whitespaces with certain interval

Tags: regex

I'd let use regex to find all whitespaces after given number of interval. 
for example, if interval is 3 for following string the result should be

```
string = "this is a test for regex" 

string = "this(select)is a(select)test(select)for(select)regex"
```

the whitespace after `is` should not be selected since the interval is 3 and the length of `is` only 2

I did this `^(?=.{3,})\s$` but no luck. Thank you

Comment: everything , start and end

Comment: What do you do in case of: `a b c` --> `a(space)b(space)c`

Comment: I don't quite understand. Am I correct in assuming that the *interval* is the previous word's length + 1? So you're trying to match spaces after two-letter words for the above? e.g. `is` in your example or `my` in `my dog`?

Comment: @dvo it should only select the whitespace after b

Comment: @ctwheels it means select first whitespace after length of given interval

Comment: @galaxyan I don't know what you mean by `interval`? What defines an `interval`?

Comment: @galaxyan what regex engine / programming language are you using? Does it support positive look behinds `(?<=...)`?

Comment: @ctwheels the interval given by user, at this example is 3

Comment: @galaxyan my point is: Does [`(?<!\b\w{2})\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/g8FdrX/2) work for you? You would replace `2` with your user's input and subtract 1 (assuming it's greater than 0)

Comment: @ctwheels thank you. it works for given number 3 but not for other number.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how it fails? For example: [`(?<!\b\w{4})\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/g8FdrX/3)

Comment: @ctwheels if the interval number change to 5. the example should output {this is(select)a test(select)for regex}

Comment: @galaxyan I'm not exactly sure what `interval` is then - I know the user inputs it, but how does it relate to the sentence and how are the specific spaces selected based on that interval?

Comment: @galaxyan I think I finally understand. Does [`.{3,}?\K\s`](https://regex101.com/r/g8FdrX/4) work for you?

Comment: @ctwheels works. thank you

Comment: @galaxyan I've added this as an answer below with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your regex engine, you can use either of the following:

#### `\K` Reset Method

If your engine supports `\K`.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/g8FdrX/6)

```
.{3,}?\K\s+
```

This method matches any character 3 or more times (but as few as possible), then **resets the pattern's match**, then matches one or more whitespace characters.

#### Capture Group Method

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/g8FdrX/5)

```
(.{3,}?)\s+
```

Replace with `$1`

This method **captures** any character 3 or more times (but as few as possible), then matches one or more whitespace characters. You would then replace the matches with first capture group's match.

---

The `?` that follows a quantifier (in the cases above `{3,}`) causes it to match in a *lazy* manner, meaning that once it satisfies at least 3 matches and finds a whitespace character, it'll stop (this prevents it from matching the whole line up to the last space).

The `\K` token resets the pattern's match. This means that nothing preceding this toke will be captured in the overall match (resulting in only the whitespace characters being matched)

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
.{3,}?(\s)
```

- `.{3,}?` - lazily match any 3 chars
- `(\s)` - capture the whitespace which follows

Your desired spaces would be in `$1`.

https://regex101.com/r/7iWjQO/1